# Application closes when I try to add a change listener to a seek bar (Android Studio, Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, crash, seekbar

I'm trying to write a simple app with a TextView and Seekbar using Android Studio and Kotlin. I want the TextView to display the current progress of the SeekBar.

I'm running into trouble when using setOnSeekBarChangeListener with my seekbar. The app crashes immediately after running the code and there are no errors.

This is what my code looks like:

```
    val bar = findViewById<SeekBar>(R.id.bar)
    val bartext = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.bartext)

    bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener{
        override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
            bartext.text = bar.progress.toString()
        }

        override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar) {
            // Write code to perform some action when touch is started.
        }

        override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar) {
            // Write code to perform some action when touch is stopped.
        }
```

When I hit run there's a prompt on the emulator saying "App keeps stopping" and gives me the option to open the app again.

Comment: Post error log.

Comment: *there are no errors* there are errors and you can see them in the error log.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** While the exact solution will be known only after seeing the log, as a correct implementation you can try this:

Instead of this line:

```
bartext.text = bar.progress.toString()
```

Write this:

```
bartext.text = progress.toString()
```

That's it. Hope it helps.